# JS - Is there a more efficient way to compare values in an array to a target search term

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, for-loop, search

I am aiming to search an array of objects for one that's title is similar or matches a search term exactly. The problem is I would like to prioritise exact matches over matches that only contain the string.

The current code does this by looping multiple times, each time with a different condition, and returns the object if it matches.

```js
class Item {
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

function findMatch(term) {
    const items = [new Item("term"), new Item("Longer Term"), new Item("Completely Different Title")];

    // Check if any match the search term exactly
    for (var item of items) {
        if (item.title === term) return item;
    }

    // Check if any match the search term, ignoring case
    for (var item of items) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()) return item;
    }

    // Check if any start with the search term
    for (var item of items) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) return item;
    }

    // Check if any end with the search term
    for (var item of items) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase().endsWith(term.toLowerCase())) return item;
    }

    // Check if any contain the search term
    for (var item of items) {
        if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) return item;
    }
    
    return null;
}

console.log(findMatch("different")); // Item with title "Completely Different Title"
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently, like in one loop - or is there a better way to search strings?

I have looked into using the Levenshtein algorithm however this does not work for searching "Comp" and getting the Item with title "Completely Different Title", as a lot more is different between "Comp" and "Completely Different Title" than there is between "Comp" and "term" - Is there a way to incorporate the same idea into this search?

Comment: You could put them all in the one loop?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the aim by putting them in separate loops is so that the conditions don't overlap, for example if the first element does not match exactly I don't want it to also check if the first element matches ignoring case until the entire array has already been checked.

Comment: You may use a `break` in loop...

Comment: @MisterJojo how would you suggest that would be implemented?

Comment: @Bobcat33 I don't think it matters since you're returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for *efficiency*, the only improvement I can think of that would reduce processing would be to lowercase the strings in advance, instead of lowercasing each value inside each loop. Though, it'd probably be a very marginal improvement and be unnoticeable in most cases.

```
class Item {
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.lowerTitle = title.toLowerCase();
    }
}
function findMatch(term) {
    const lowerTerm = term.toLowerCase();
    // use item.lowerTitle and lowerTerm when appropriate
```

The logic you want to implement fundamentally requires a loop over all elements looking for one condition, followed by another loop over all elements looking for another, etc. So there's no real way to improve the computational complexity over your current implementation.

You could combine some or all of the conditions with a regular expression, but that would break the priority sequence of match types to be returned.

If you want to make the code *shorter* and easier to maintain, that's easy enough - you could use an array of callbacks that get called for every item in order:

```
const comparers = [
  (a, b) => a === b,
  (a, b) => a.startsWith(b),
  (a, b) => a.endsWith(b),
  (a, b) => a.includes(b),
]
for (const fn of comparers) {
  if (fn(item.lowerTitle, lowerTerm)) return item;
}
```

> Is there a way to incorporate the same idea into this search?

Checking the Levenshtein distance would be a bit different. Instead of looping over items and returning one when it matches, you'd need to loop over all items unconditionally and return the best match after the loop finishes.

```
let bestItem;
let lowestDistance = Infinity;
for (const item of items) {
  const dist = compare(item.lowerTitle, lowerTerm);
  if (dist < lowestDistance) {
    bestItem = item;
    lowestDistance = dist;
  }
}
return bestItem;
```

You'd do this *at least* instead of the `.includes` check at the end. Depending on what logic you want, you might also remove the `startsWith` and `endsWith` checks in exchange too.

Comment: I do currently implement the same loop you mentioned for finding the shortest Levenshtein distance but as I mentioned I can't get it to correctly assume that "Comp" would result in "Completely Different Title" so I decided to use startsWith as a workaround, is there a better way to use the Levenshtein algorithm for more accurate results?

Comment: You might take a substring from the start (and end?) the same length of the search term, then compare *that* one's distance from the term. So `comp` -> `copm` would be seen as a close match. But this would have to still be done in a earlier loop separate from the one comparing the overall distance between the term and title. Perhaps return the lowest distance substring item if its distance is below a certain threshold, and if not, loop again, comparing the distance of the full titles.

Answer (score 0):

You might assign a `score` to your items depending on "similarity" whatever it is, then filter and sort the items by that score and return the matches:

```js
class Item {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
const items = [new Item("term"), new Item("Longer Term"), new Item("Completely Different Title")];

function findMatch(term) {
  for (var item of items) {
    // Check if any match the search term exactly
    if (item.title === term) item.score = 10000;

    // Check if any match the search term, ignoring case
    else if (item.title.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()) item.score = 1000;

    // Check if any start with the search term
    else if (item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())) item.score = 100;

    // Check if any end with the search term
    else if (item.title.toLowerCase().endsWith(term.toLowerCase())) item.score = 10;

    // Check if any contain the search term
    else if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())) item.score = 1;
  }
  return items.filter(i => 0 < i.score).sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score).map(i => delete i.score && i)
}

console.log(findMatch("different")); // Item with title "Completely Different Title"
console.log(findMatch("term"));
```